# Image upload in Android WebViews

Tags: java, android-studio, button, file-upload, webview

I have a website developed in React where the user clicks on a button to upload an image from his device. It's working fine on my website.

I have converted this website into an Android App using Android Webview Java.

Now how to make this React button work like a Java button in Android Studio so that when I grant "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission, and when the user clicks on this button in Webview - he should be redirected to select an image from his device.

**SAMPLE HTML CODE** -

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Above code website link](https://effortless-crostata-bc9ce0.netlify.app/)

Comment: @blackapps I have a web application that was developed using React JS, there is an "image upload" button in it, now I wanted to create an android app for the same application so I used Android WebViews and gave my website link in the Webview load url. When the "image upload" button is clicked in my Android App, nothing is happening. Let me know if you want any further clarifications.

Comment: Android app's do not need the permission to read external storage if they will let the user pick an image. And i still do not see a button.

Comment: @blackapps I'm a beginner to this Android, I still can't understand this statement ` i still do not see a button.` please help me what I have to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247360/discussion-between-sureshtechi-and-blackapps).

Comment: @blackapps I have added the react code for the button above

Comment: @blackapps I have added a sample HTML code above as you mentioned

Comment: @blackapps nothing happens when I click this button in Webviews, it should actually redirect me to the device storage to choose an image right but it didn't. Leave about the permissions sorry.

Comment: Indeed nothing happens. Has noting to do with react native. You better rewrite your post or make a new one where you first post this simple htm souce and then ask why the button does nothing. I heard that before and you can find discussions on stackoverflow where this is discussed. You have to fiddle around with settings for webviewcliwnt and such... i think.. "Html form input does nothing in WebView". Google that. And use an `android` tag. Not one for `android-studio`

Comment: @blackapps Thank you so much for patiently listening to my comments, will post a new one as you mentioned.